# understanding Array#uniq function calls

Tags: ruby

If I use the following code:

```
class Item
  attr_reader :item_name, :qty

  def initialize(item_name, qty)
    @item_name = item_name
    @qty = qty
  end

  def to_s
   "Item (#{@item_name}, #{@qty})"
  end

  def hash
    p "hash has been called"
    self.item_name.hash ^ self.qty.hash
  end

  def eql?(other_item)
    puts "#eql? invoked"
    @item_name == other_item.item_name && @qty == other_item.qty
  end  
end

p Item.new("abcd", 1).hash

items = [Item.new("abcd", 1), Item.new("abcd", 1), Item.new("abcd", 1)]
p items.uniq

"hash has been called"
4379041107527942435
"hash has been called"
"hash has been called"
#eql? invoked
"hash has been called"
#eql? invoked
"hash has been called"
"hash has been called"
"hash has been called"
[Item (abcd, 1)]
```

I'm interpreting this to mean that the #hash method is being used to generate unique integers for each object, where then #eql? is invoked to check if the integers are equal as a way to check for duplicates. Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Sorry, one more question - #eql? still has it's own definition in class Array, versus the one we see defined here in class Item right? Because Item::#eql? can only compare objects...

Comment: Yes, `eql?` on any class only compares objects of that class. `Array#eql?` would be used if any element of `items` was itself an `Array`.

Answer (score 4):

No, your interpretation is not correct.

`hash` does *not* generate unique integers, which is precisely *why* the `eql?` call is necessary, and `eql?` is *not* called on the integers but on the elements.

This is just plain old hashing, exactly identical to what is used in `Hash`, `Set`, and `SortedSet`.

`hash` is a hash function, i.e. a function which maps a large (potentially infinite) input space to a smaller, fixed-size output space. Since the output space is smaller than the input space, there *must* necessarily be at least two distinct objects with the same hash code, thus the hash values are *not* unique! (This is called the *Pigeonhole Principle*. Intuitively: if you have two drawers and three socks, then there must be at least one drawer with at least two socks in them.)

*Because* the hash values are not unique, two identical hash values don't tell you anything. If two hash values are *different*, then you know *definitely* that the two objects are also different. But if two hash values are the *same*, then the objects *could* still be different (this is called a *Hash Collision*), that's why you have to double-check using `eql?`.

Comment: Good explanation. It's worth noting that there are situations where hash codes can be used for identification in a probabilistic sense, when it's not possible to compare two objects that have the same hash code. In such cases one often can construct a hash code to keep the probability of a collision to less than some pre-defined (tiny) value. You seem to know a lot about socks as well as coding, so I'm wondering if you could help me with a problem I have. Very few of my socks have mates.  I found a couple in our dryer's sock trap, but I've no idea how I lost the others.  Any advice?

Comment: Sorry, I knew that hash isn't perfect, that generic outputs are possible, just not likely. In fact I was thinking about trying to write a function that could solve for potential inputs that result in the same hash state as an object of interest. 

But what I was really confused about was why #eql? was being called. So what your saying is that Item#eql is being called, not Fixnum#eql? and that it's being used to double check the hashes??

I don't understand then why Array#uniq would even bother with the hash check if all it's going boil down to is a direct comparison of the objects elements.